# Should I use Python pandas or write custom code in C for reading and filtering data from a multi-gigabyte CSV file?

Tags: python, c, pandas, csv, optimization

I have a 13 GB CSV file and I need to read the file and filter data from it. I am using pandas and reading it in chunks, but it takes too long. Are there any other libraries in python that are faster than pandas or writing custom code in C would be a better option?

I am using following code:

```
input_df=pd.read_csv("input file",chunksize=60000)
frames=[]
for i in input_df:
    filter_df=i[i["Column1"].str.contains("given string")|i["column2"].str.contains("given string")|i["column3"].str.contains("given string")]
    frame=pd.DataFrame(filter_df)
    frames.append(frame)
output_df=pd.concat(frames)
output_df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

I have 8 GB ram so have to read data in chunks.

Comment: "half of too long" (assuming you can code run twice as fast) is still "too long". I suggest you change the algorithm, not the language.

Comment: It would help if you shared a [mcve] code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am just using pd.read_csv(inputfile,chunksize=60000). i just have 8 gb ram so reading data in chunks

Comment: Maybe try read and process line-by-line (not by "chunk")?

Comment: Can you provide your code responsible for filtering?

Comment: The time it will probably take you to write C code that runs as fast as Python + Pandas is likely greater than the time it will save you.

Comment: yes sure, i have shared the code

Comment: @pmg That algorithm looks linear to me, so it's not as if you can optimize in that regard. What I'd first do is see how long simply reading the 13GB takes and compare how high the overhead really is.

Comment: I'd suggest using a tool like [py-spy](https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/) to get an idea where the time is spent. The built-in profiler may also help but it measures functions only so for that I'd suggest splitting the code into functions that do the reading, filtering and writing. Most likely the time is spent in the filtering part I'd guess. Depending on the input, the `contains` check might be quite expensive, are you sure that a comparison with `==` isn't more appropriate?

Comment: okay @Bluehorn, i will try using py-spy and I think i need to use contains as "given string"   would be present inside the big stings stored inside rows.

Comment: How much time is this taking and what is your target time? How much RAM does it use and how much RAM can you spare? Depending on what you are searching and the data you might in a first sed simply filter lines matching a criteria (without csv parsing) and parse the filtered lines (e.g. `grep "given string" < input.csv > output.csv`). Depending on how man lines match this might greatly reduce parsing time... obviously if the csv contains escaped fields with newlines then this becomes harder to do without parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas and Numpy are built using C, so I don't see how you will gain a better speed even if you code in pure C instead writing bad C code might mess it up even further.
Try focusing on improving your algorithm or the way you are currently reading it.

if all you want to do is read a CSV file and filter data based on whether it contains a certain string then I think reading line by line would be a better approach.

```
# store your results here
result = {"col1":[], "col2":[], "col3":[]}
to_check = "some string"
reset_after = 1000
current_line = 0

fp = open('filename.csv', 'r')
while ((line := fp.readline()) != ''):
    current_line += 1

    # Now, create a dataframe out of current result dictionary and save it
    df = DataFrame(result)
    df.to_csv("result_file.csv", mode='a', index=False, header=False)

    # reset after saving every reset_after line has reached
    if current_line >= reset_after:
        result = {"col1":[], "col2":[], "col3":[]}

    val1, val2, val3 = line.split(",")
    if (col1 == to_check) or (col2 == to_check) or (col3 == to_check):
        result['col1'].append(val1)
        result['col2'].append(val2)
        result['col3'].append(val3)
```

Comment: I have shared the code.

Comment: yes, check the edited answer

Comment: `fp.readlines()` is going to load the whole contents of the file in RAM, and given that the file is 13GB and OP has 8GB of memory this cannot work. You can simply iterate over the lines of a file by looping over the file `for line in fp:`.

Comment: @Bakuriu no, fp.readlines() will yield one line at a time. And since we are resetting the results dict after every result_after line has reached, so it won't impact his RAM.

Comment: @AquibShaikh `open('a.txt').readlines() -> ['A\n', 'B\n', 'C\n']` `readlines` creates a list, this requires the whole file to be read... iterating over the file avoids loading the whole file into memory and python will use a buffer. [Python's official tutorial says: If you want to read **all the lines** of a file in a list you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()` .](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: @Bakuriu yes I think you are right here, I mistaken readline() for readlines() here

Comment: "Pandas and Numpy are built using C, so I don't see how you will gain a better speed even if you code in pure C". The python interpreter is also written in C, so if that logic were universally true, all python code should be as fast as c code. The truth is more complex and while pandas is well optimized it's still a general purpose library, so you most likely can do better for this particular use case if you wanted to.

Comment: Also note that reading a csv file line per line and parsing every line separately won't work if you have quoted newlines in your data, so the proposed solution doesn't handle arbitrary csv data contrary to the original code as far as I can see.

Comment: @Voo Reading, writing operation are more dependent on the system and storage as opposed to language. Yes it is a factor but in the current scene a better algorithm would do much more than switching to another language.

Comment: @aquib You'd think so, but in reality particularly high level languages have an*awful* overhead when simply reading and writing io. Memory mapping files,  async io and taking advantage of allocation patterns can do a great deal. Also what do you mean with better algorithm? The current one is linear and I don't see any algorithmic improvements, it's just a question of going for a better implementation.

Comment: @Voo The current one is relatively smarter approach which avoids loading into memory too much